# Overlay custom axes to a plot created by symbols

Tags: r

Struggling with this one.  I have 25 data items that I want plotted with bubbles in 5 columns.
The plot can be re-created thus:

```
 xcord <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
 ycord <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
 zsize <- c(2,1,2,3,6,8,9,1,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,5,5,5,5,1,8,1,1,12)
```

Save the parameters before I change them:

```
 op <- par()
 dev.off()
```

Change the parameters:

```
 par (mfrow=c(1,0), mar=c(2,2,2,2), oma=c(2,2,2,2))
```

Plot using symbols:

```
 symbols(xcord, ycord, zsize, inches=0.3, fg="white", bg="red", xlab="Events", ylab="Diagnoses", tck=0, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")     

 mtext("Rheumatic diagnoses by cerebrovasular events", line=2, font=2, cex=1.2)
```

I am happy with the above plot and deliberately used tck=0, xaxt="n", yaxt="n" to clear the axes.  I want to manually overlay custom text, controlled with custom co-ordinates (which work with the sysmbols plot), but have not been able to do it.  I have tried some of the par arguments and the axes function.

I also tried leaving the axes on:

```
 symbols(xcord, ycord, zsize, inches=0.3, fg="white", bg="red", xlab="Events", ylab="Diagnoses")
```

but do not know how to change the output (1,2,3,4,5) to my own custom axes labels.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `axis` function (see `?axis` for details), e.g. to replace the `1:5` with *A, B, C, D, E*:

```
axis(side=1, at=1:5, labels=LETTERS[1:5])
```